# How to tag the sound segments in Audacity

Tags: wav, audacity, tagging

I am working with *large amount of short wav-files* (over 900 of them). The upper track is used as a reference (low quality) under which I arrange complementary smaller wav files (highest quality).

**It will be great if I could write some notes to identify individual tracks. Is there any way how to do this?** At least the ID of segments.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not to use `Label Track`? Simply click on a given point in time and press `Ctrl+B` or choose: **Tracks** **->** **Add Label At Selection**. Afterwards you can export your label file, which can be easily parsed.